" Looking for new and fast ODE Solver" .Improving the Run time for my numerical model with 2 ODES solved using solve_ivp
I am trying to solve heat diffusion(Temperature) and Mass transfer (concentration)equation for a spherical particle.
I have a mesh size of 20 circles, with temperature and concentration value at each point.
My general idea was to expand these equation using Forward difference method and solve using "solve_ivp" from "scipy". The run time for this 5000 sec of time slot is almost 30 min.

(∂C)/(∂t)=(D_gas*(∂^2 c)/(∂r^2 ) + 2/r*D_gas*(∂C)/(∂r)+ (∂D_gas)/∂r*(∂C)/(∂r)) + r_CO2



(∂T)/(∂t)=(α*(∂^2 T)/(∂r^2 ) + 2/r α*(∂T)/(∂r) + ∂α/∂r*(∂T)/(∂r))+Q



num_points = 20

So together there will be 40 equations at each mesh value.
I have stored all the values in an array T : 20 values of concentration and 20 values of temperature.
res = solve_ivp(solve, [0,5000], in_cond, method='RK45', atol=1e-8, rtol=1e-8)

def T&C(T, dt, t):

T&C is the main function under which these 2 equations are written , with if and else conditions at boundary and other points within  the spherical particle.
This function contains the main loops of the code which , i think is time consuming.
def T&C(T, dt, t):
# For Concentration 

    func = []                         #Empty list containing function values
    func.append(0)
    for i in range(1, num_points):

        if i != num_points-1:              # For nodes 1 to 19 , from centre to second last node.
            diff1 = Deff*(T[i+1]-2*T[i]+T[i-1])/delta**2         
            diff2 = Deff*(b-1)*(T[i+1]-T[i-1])/(2/delta/r_act)
            diff = (diff1+diff2)/eps 
        else :  diff = float(Deff*((cs-2*T[i]+T[i-1])/delta**2 + (b-1)*(cs-T[i-          1])/delta/r_act/2)/eps)
            
    func.append(diff) 

# for Temperature
      
   func.append(0)
   for i in range(1, num_points):
        
        if i != num_points-1: 
           diff1 = ai*(T[i+num_points+1]-2*T[i+num_points]+T[i+num_points-1])/delta**2  
           diff2 = ai*(b-1)*(T[i+num_points+1]-T[i+num_points-1])/2/delta/r_act
           diff3 = (T[i+num_points+1]-T[i+num_points-1])/2/delta*dlambdadr/csolid/rho_i
           diff = diff1+diff2+diff3

        else: 
            diff1 = ai*(Ts-2*T[i+num_points]+T[i+num_points-1])/delta**2
            diff2 = ai*(b-1)*(Ts-T[i+num_points-1])/delta/r_act/2
            diff = float(diff1+diff2).


       
       func.append(diff)


# Function defining time steps
def solve(t, T):

    
    time_m1 = times[-1]                         
    times.append(t)
    dt = t-time_m1                             #  Calculating the time difference
    func = points_with_conc(T, dt, t)          # Call the function 'points_with_conc' with parameters T, dt, and t
    #breakpoint()
    print(t,X_list[-1])                                  #Print current time
    
    return func

I would like to know which other libraries can be used other than numpy , scipy , so that i can reduce the execution time and improve the code.

Since you are tagging Julia, you should check out https://docs.sciml.ai/DiffEqDocs/stable/ which is arguably the foremost diffeq system out there. I believe there are also Python bindings, if you don't want to program in Julia.
